# libsndfile: Read wav skipping JUNK chunk

Tags: audio, wav, libsndfile, riff

I had been using libsndfile library. But only recently, I found some of my wav files have this extra JUNK section inside and libsndfile is not categorizing it as JUNK but simply reading this as data.

The structure of my wav file is shown here:

[image: test.wav with JUNK section].

I want to know how I should be able to SKIP or ignore this JUNK section. 
Note that `fmt` is now at offset (`off=56`) instead of `off=20`, which is when my test.wav does not have any JUNK.

If the solution is to use some other library than libsndfile, then please suggest, which one would allow me to programmatically skip this JUNK block.

Comment: I'm the libsndfile author. Can you please post a link to this file or a similar one?

Comment: Hi Erik, Thanks for following up. I later discovered that libsndfile was working fine (i.e., JUNK was automatically ignored by libsndfile).

Comment: +1 for bringing [RiffPad](http://www.menasoft.com/blog/?p=34) to my attention.